# axios combine url api and why return promise not value?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm try combine different url api json and add by key nested array objects. In console.log getting like this, in key `task` returned `Promise` object, how resolve to get [[PromiseValue]]:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
  0:
    description: "description"
    id: 121
    name: "list1"
    task: Promise
      __proto__: Promise
      [[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
      [[PromiseValue]]: Array(2)
        0:
          description: "description task1"
          id: 10
          name: "task1"
          __proto__: Object
       1:
          description: "description task2"
          id: 11
          name: "task2"
          __proto__: Object
       length: 2
     __proto__: Array(0)
     __proto__: Object
  1: {id: 9, name: "list2", description: "description2", task: Promise}
     length: 2
     __proto__: Array(0)
```

expected like json static data:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
  0:
    description: "false"
    id: 121
    name: "list1"
    task: Array(2)
      0: {id: 10, name: "task1", description: "description task1", state: false, position: 1}
      1: {id: 11, name: "task2", description: "description task2", state: true position: 2}
      length: 2
      __proto__: Array(0)
  __proto__: Object
  1:
    description: "false"
    id: 9
    name: "list2"
    task: Array(2)
      0: {id: 3, name: "task1", description: "description task1", state: false, position: 3}
      1: {id: 7, name: "task2", description: "description task2", state: false, position: 5}
      length: 2
      __proto__: Array(0)
  __proto__: Object
  length: 2
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

in react: 
first api is task list `'/sets'`, second api url is tasks `'/sets/' + c.id + '/tasks'`

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'api';
    componentDidMount() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        axios
            .get('/sets')
            .then(response => {
                const taskAndList = response.data.map(c => {
                    const taskList = axios.get('/sets/' + c.id + '/tasks').then(res => {
                        let tasks = res.data;
                        const taskitem = tasks.map(p => {
                            return {
                                id: p.id,
                                name: p.name,
                                description: p.description
                            };
                        });
                        return taskitem;
                    });
                    return {
                        id: c.id,
                        name: c.name,
                        description: c.description,
                        task: taskList
                    };
                });
                runInAction(() => {
                    console.log(taskAndList);
                    this.todos = taskAndList;
                    this.isLoading = false;
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

Comment: You have quite a bit of nested `Promise` action going on here and it is hard to follow.  If looks like you need to resolve `taskList` at some point and you aren't doing that.  Because I see a request with `axios` being done inside of a `map`, it feels like you might need a `Promise.all` somewhere in there too.

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified a little bit, but I obtained the same result, I'm still fighting to get an array of objects [[PromiseValue]]

```
    axios.defaults.baseURL = 'api';

    async getsecondApi(id) {
        let strr = [];
        await axios
            .get('/sets/' + id + '/tasks')
            .then(function(response) {
                this.strr.push(response.data);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        return strr;
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        await axios
            .get('/sets')
            .then(response => {
                const tempTodos = response.data;
                tempTodos.map(todo => (todo.task = this.getsecondApi(todo.id)));
                console.log(tempTodos);
                this.todos = tempTodos;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

update, now is working combine api json
this is code:

```
    @action async Retrieve() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        await axios
            .get('/sets')
            .then(response => {
                let tempTodos = response.data;
                tempTodos.forEach(todo => (todo.editing = false));
                let todosWithTasks = tempTodos.map(todo => {
                    let tasks = false;
                    axios
                        .get('/sets/' + todo.id + '/tasks')
                        .then(response2 => {
                            tasks = response2.data;
                            tasks.forEach(todo => (todo.editing = false));
                            todo.task = tasks;
                            return tasks;
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                    return todo;
                });

                runInAction(() => {
                    this.todos = toJS(todosWithTasks, recurseEverything);
                    this.isLoading = false;
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```